# AAPT err with build-tools 24

Tags: android, continuous-integration

I updated one project to build-tools 24 and face a problem on one ci-server ( snap-ci )

```
:android:mergeNoMapsNoAnalyticsForFDroidDebugResourcesAAPT err(Facade for 732455009): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt)
AAPT err(Facade for 732455009): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/lib64/libc++.so)
AAPT err(Facade for 1022762861): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt)
AAPT err(Facade for 1022762861): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/lib64/libc++.so)
AAPT err(Facade for 296243528): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt)
AAPT err(Facade for 296243528): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/lib64/libc++.so)
AAPT err(Facade for 1716800217): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt)
AAPT err(Facade for 1716800217): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/lib64/libc++.so)
AAPT err(Facade for 1024074265): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt)
AAPT err(Facade for 1024074265): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/lib64/libc++.so)
AAPT err(Facade for 507300997): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt)
AAPT err(Facade for 507300997): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/lib64/libc++.so)
AAPT err(Facade for 208544674): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt)
AAPT err(Facade for 208544674): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/lib64/libc++.so)
AAPT err(Facade for 1889044593): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt)
AAPT err(Facade for 1889044593): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/lib64/libc++.so)
AAPT err(Facade for 1034526638): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt)
AAPT err(Facade for 1034526638): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/lib64/libc++.so)
AAPT err(Facade for 1216050111): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt)
AAPT err(Facade for 1216050111): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/lib64/libc++.so)
AAPT err(Facade for 1695535977): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt)
AAPT err(Facade for 1695535977): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/lib64/libc++.so)
AAPT err(Facade for 371813291): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt)
AAPT err(Facade for 371813291): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/lib64/libc++.so)
AAPT err(Facade for 136054908): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt)
AAPT err(Facade for 136054908): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/lib64/libc++.so)
AAPT err(Facade for 1373763831): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt)
AAPT err(Facade for 1373763831): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/lib64/libc++.so)
AAPT err(Facade for 1980150991): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt)
AAPT err(Facade for 1980150991): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/lib64/libc++.so)
AAPT err(Facade for 1407743214): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt)
AAPT err(Facade for 1407743214): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/lib64/libc++.so)
AAPT err(Facade for 652380795): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt)
AAPT err(Facade for 652380795): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/lib64/libc++.so)
AAPT err(Facade for 824755698): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt)
AAPT err(Facade for 1501464593): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt)
AAPT err(Facade for 1501464593): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/lib64/libc++.so)
AAPT err(Facade for 2112858062): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt)
AAPT err(Facade for 2112858062): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/lib64/libc++.so)
AAPT err(Facade for 824755698): /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/lib64/libc++.so)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_2" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /var/go/android/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Anyone knows how to work around this?

Comment: Upgrade the OS https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197074